# Detect pending sheduled shutdown Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Tags: shutdown

Before systemd, one used to be able to see a shutdown process in the list of processes (e.g. `ps -ef | grep shutdown`).  Now however, the most recent advice I can find is to use `systemctl status`, but I'm not having any luck:

```
root@m________a:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
root@m________a:~# shutdown -r 14:00
Shutdown scheduled for Mon 2016-10-10 14:00:00 BST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
root@m________a:~# ps -ef | grep "shutdown"
root     10584 10508  0 13:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto shutdown
root@m________a:~# systemctl status systemd-halt.service
● systemd-halt.service - Halt
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-halt.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-halt.service(8)
root@m________a:~# systemctl status systemd-reboot.service 
● systemd-reboot.service - Reboot
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-reboot.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-halt.service(8)
root@m________a:~# systemctl status systemd-poweroff.service 
● systemd-poweroff.service - Power-Off
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-halt.service(8)
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can explain how I can detect a pending scheduled shutdown and, indeed, why such a shutdown doesn't seem to show up using `systemctl`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled
```

This was added to systemd 220 release as explained here: 
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Systemd-Kill-Shutdownd

Answer (score 2):

```
systemctl status systemd-shutdownd.service
```

[manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-shutdownd.8.html) for the service:

> `systemd-shutdownd.service` is a system service that implements scheduled shutdowns, as exposed by shutdown(8). `systemd-shutdownd.service` is automatically activated on request and terminates itself when it is unused.

---

When not active:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-shutdownd.service
● systemd-shutdownd.service - Delayed Shutdown Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-shutdownd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-shutdownd.service(8)
```

---

When active:

```
 $ sudo shutdown +100
 Shutdown scheduled for ma 2016-10-10 17:12:56 CEST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
 $ systemctl status systemd-shutdownd.service 
 ● systemd-shutdownd.service - Delayed Shutdown Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-shutdownd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since ma 2016-10-10 15:32:56 CEST; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-shutdownd.service(8)
 Main PID: 3129 (systemd-shutdow)
   Status: "Shutting down at Mon 2016-10-10 17:12:56 CEST (poweroff)..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-shutdownd.service
           └─3129 /lib/systemd/systemd-shutdownd

okt 10 15:32:56 x systemd[1]: Started Delayed Shutdown Service.
okt 10 15:32:56 x systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Service...
okt 10 15:32:56 x systemd-shutdownd[3129]: Shutting down at Mon 2016-1...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Thanks --- but although I have the `poweroff`, `reboot` and `halt` services, I get this for `shutdownd` ...

    $ sudo systemctl status systemd-shutdownd.service
    [sudo] password for john: 
    ● systemd-shutdownd.service
       Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
       Active: inactive (dead)
    
This happens whether or not I have issued a `shutdown` but `shutdown` still works in the way one expects.  Status reported is the same whether requested `sudo` or not.

EDIT: apologies, I cannot seem to put the code in a formatted block

Comment: Funky. Ill have an extra look later (17:00 so time to head home) :P  Edit the question instead of making a comment. Then you can format ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On newer systems (running `systemd` 220 and above, check with `systemd --version`) 
the `systemd-shutdownd.service` has been removed and the *simple* way is to 
`cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`. If the file exists a shutdown is pending
and the file will contain something like

```
USEC=1547919000000000
WARN_WALL=1
MODE=poweroff
```

I wrote a little script to handle that case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -r /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled ]; then
    source /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled;
    echo "System will shutdown to mode=$MODE at $(date --date="@$(( USEC / 1000000 ))")";
    exit 0;
else
    echo "No pending shutdown";
    exit 1;
fi
```

Further reading:

- [The shutdown program on a modern systemd-based Linux system](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/SystemdVersionOfShutdown)

Answer (score 0):

The script by PerlDuck I found did not echo "No pending shutdown" if shutdown -c was issued to cancel a previous scheduled shutdown. The scheduled file in /run/systemd/shutdown would still remain (Ubuntu 16.04) and thus checking it would always give me the old answer. Of course if nothing was scheduled in the first place it functions correctly.

I feel there is a technically better way to do it rather than what I did using a string comparison; but with a small modification to check the result given by busctl get-property it works for me:

```
string="$(busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager ScheduledShutdown)"
if [[ "$string" =~ \ 0$ ]]; then
    echo "No pending shutdown"
    exit 1;
else
    source /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled
    echo "System will shutdown to mode=$MODE at $(date --date="@$(( USEC / 1000000 ))")";
    exit 0;
fi
```